# New answers only show after several hours' delay

Tags: support, caching

When I answer a question on Stack Overflow, it appears as an answer on my laptop, as usual.

However when I view it on my iMac it's not there until about 3-5 hours later.

The same thing happens vice-versa.

This makes it almost impossible to have an answer accepted in time before another answer comes in.

I think you guys working at Stack Overflow should look into this bug.

I'm running Microsoft Windows 7 on my laptop with Google Chrome Dev and Apple Mac OS X Lion on my iMac with Google Chrome Stable.

EDIT 1: [Here is a link to a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551497/loading-too-many-images-slows-down-my-website/8551544#8551544)

EDIT 2: I've e-mailed a couple of my friends and he can't see my answer, so it's not my computer's or my ISP's fault. I and a couple of my friends have eircom, some of them have UPC, and the rest have Vodafone.

EDIT 3: I'm not behind a proxy, VPN, Tor, or anything like that.

Comment: *"This makes it almost impossible to have an answer accepted in time before another answer comes in."* There is a 15 minutes waiting time for accepting answers, to prevent exactly this, premature accepting of an answer. I'm pretty sure other answers will be added in the meantime, depending on the popularity of the question. *Edit:* This comment was made before the time was added.

Comment: I can see your last answer just fine. Is the timestamp also wrong of the answers, or are those correct?

Comment: @Bobby I can't see it on my laptop yet

Comment: Well, clear the browser cache. If it isn't there then...well...try another browser. If it isn't there then...uuuhhhh...aggressive ISP caching?

Comment: Now we need your geographical location, including that of your friends. Maybe one the CDN servers is misbehaving.

Comment: @Bobby Tried clearing everything (history, cache, cookies, bookmarks, passwords, Autofill, downloads), still doesn't work. It's not aggressive ISP caching because as I said in the question lots of my friends aren't seeing anything.

Comment: Does it happen on meta too? (Try posting an answer to this question, and add a comment here - that seems to work fine). Do you have any currently "invisible" answers, and if so on which question? (Your last answer is timestamped real close to the question's post date.)

Comment: @Bobby I'm in Co. Dublin, Ireland. My Latitude/Longitude is according to Google Maps 53.346629,-6.424389.

Comment: Okay, maybe we'll find somebody else from around there...but in the mean time, could you try out a proxy-service to check if your answer is showing up there?

Comment: @Mat I need to wait 4 hrs. I don't currently have any "invisible" answers.

Comment: @Bobby I'm not big in this subject, can you recommend me one?

Comment: @Bobby, I thought the CDNs [only serve *static* content](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/the-speed-of-light-sucks/)?

Comment: @Arjan: Whoops, I was under the impression that the whole network is served by the CDN servers...my mistake.

Comment: I've changed the tags into `bug` again, as that seems to be what you're thinking. But I really cannot imagine why one computer in your place would show the question differently than others using the very same internet connection. Are you logged in into SO on both computers? What if you use some private browsing mode? (Beware that ISPs might use proxy servers without you having to configure anything for that, but it's unlikely that different ISPs would use the same machines for that.)

Comment: Just to be sure: your friends know they [shouldn't be looking for your real name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551497/loading-too-many-images-slows-down-my-website/8551544#8551544), right? And that the sort order might be different? What do they see for "asked/answered .. hours ago"?

Comment: An even easier check: what number do they see in "5 answers"?

Comment: @Arjan They see 4 hours ago, just asked

Comment: @Arjan They can see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my ISP from eircom to upc.

Fixed now and browsing is much, *much* faster!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you looked at the question on one computer, then posted using another, then looked using the first again:

The servers tell your browsers (and possible proxy server) to [cache for 1 minute at most](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8551497%2Floading-too-many-images-slows-down-my-website%2F&submit=Submit&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0):

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Expires: Sun, 18 Dec 2011 12:29:36 GMT  
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Dec 2011 12:28:36 GMT
Vary: *
```

So somehow your computers or (your ISP's) proxy server is caching far too long. If a proxy is behaving badly, then [explicitly enforcing a refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/278553/does-holding-down-ctrl-shift-while-clicking-refresh-actually-have-an-effect-in-m/278560#278560) might not work either.

But it's surely an issue with *your* computers, or *your* connection/ISP.

Comment: Not-so-fun fact as for badly behaving (hidden) ISP proxy servers: [Hijacked session: Signed in as someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86033/hijacked-session-signed-in-as-someone-else/86041#86041).

Comment: An employee from my ISP came to my house and checked it. He said that there should be nothing wrong.