# Are the private user pages cachable?

Tags: support, privacy

Please be patient with me, as I'm not too knowledgeable on this topic. This question has been prompted by [Hijacked session: Signed in as someone else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86033/hijacked-session-signed-in-as-someone-else).

When I access my user page on Stackoverflow, the first request is a GET request and the response has the cache header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=120`. The response for this request is a web-page that contains private information about me such as e-mail address, and additionally prompts additional requests, some marked `private` and some `public`.

Doesn't this `public` mean that this page is permissible for general, not per-user caching? Isn't it problematic when this page contains stuff like my e-mail address?

I mean, wouldn't **all** pages on any stackexchange site to be marked as `private` if the user is logged-in, since by definition this page will be localized to that user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Doesn't this `public` mean that this page is permissible for general, not per-user caching? Isn't it problematic when this page contains stuff like my e-mail address?

Well, yes. But that's irrelevant, because the response also contains [a `Vary: *` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44):

> A Vary field value of "*" implies that a cache cannot determine from the request headers of a subsequent request whether this response is the appropriate representation.

This basically means that the caching entity has to ask the server to revalidate the content before serving up the page, and the server won't send a 304 response in cases where it would mean serving up a page you (or rather, someone who isn't you) shouldn't see.

Of course, there's nothing stopping your ISP (or other intermediary) from [doing whatever it wants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63845/account-mixup-on-stack-overflow) despite that, but in general it should be fine.