# Clicking on an old answer in your profile (answers tab), then hitting back in the browser shows incorrect reputation

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Ok, so here's a strange *feature*

Go to your profile, click on the **answers** tab, click to page two or three or so, then click on one of the questions in the list that you have answered.

Now, once you're on that question, hit the back button to return to that selected page in the answer list, now scroll up and look at your Total Reputation, it seems to show your Total Reputation from when you answered that question, not your current Total Reputation?

**Magic** :)

**EDIT: Here's screenshots, I'm using Windows 7 with Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168**

Screenshot 1: I navigated to page 5 of my answers, as you can see my rep is fine:

[image]

Screenshot 2: I clicked on the question visible in Screenshot1 entitled (JQuery UI Tabs targeting Dynamic tag from a link)

[image]

Screenshot 3: Going back in the browser (In this case I pressed backspace to go back), you can see that my rep is a **lot** lower:

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this - either on SO or MSO. What browser/OS combo are you running?

Comment: No-repro under Chrome 18.0.1025.168

Comment: @RivieraKid I'm using Windows 7 with Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168

Comment: @Bart Try an older page and instead of hitting back try using the backspace, seems intermittent now I'm trying to reproduce it time after time.

Comment: I've tried it several times now, but still can't reproduce it. Are you running any add-ons/userscripts by any chance?

Comment: How long did you have this tab open?  Browsers cache pages...

Comment: @Bart Nah no add-ons/userscripts have you tried multiple questions on multiple pages?

Comment: @NickCraver it's happened before today, I just never actually logged it. It was a friend of mine who initally found it whilst we were at work and he thought he'd lost rep, but it seemed to be an incorrect calculation of some sort.

Comment: @mattytommo Yep, several pages, multiple questions, different orderings, etc. Still no-repro. :s

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce on Gentoo Linux x64 with Chromium 18.0.1025.168. I'll try rebooting to Win7 Home Premium x64 later.

Comment: @mattytommo - you're describing your rep being off **by over a thousand**, unless you had a really old tab open, I don't see any way this can possibly happen.  I'm looking at your rep history, there were no recalcs or anything remotely like that to explain such behavior.

Comment: @NickCraver bearing in mind I was on page 5 of my answers, which may well have been equivalent to 1000 rep at the point where I answered that question. If I refresh the page it seems fine, the fact that nobody else can reproduce it other than my work colleague (both on exactly the same laptops at work), leads me to believe the issue lies within the caching of Chrome itself, *not* SO

Comment: @mattytommo - it's certainly not an SO issue, however if your work colleague can repro I would put good money on it being a proxy server at your location.

Comment: Next time you try and repro this, go to your first answer and see if you lose all rep.

Comment: @NickCraver that's interesting because we do in fact have a proxy server, it looks like that could be the cause. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it for you :)

Comment: I have actually experienced the same thing on [a51]

Comment: This might be a good moment to check if that proxy also caches *private* pages. Like: log in and open any random page that you think your colleague has not seen yet. Next, have that colleague open the same URL. What name is shown in the top bar? (If your colleague sees your name, then see [Are the private user pages cachable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131127/are-the-private-user-pages-cachable))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds by the comments that there's a rogue/misconfigured proxy server at your workplace serving a *very* stale page...stale as in way beyond what we told that proxy to cache the page for.

This is a bug on your side, one I'd report to your IT department.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up Nick :)