# Why is the number of answers next to a question on the main page changing without the actual number of answers changing?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461817/conditional-stack-variables), there were 5 answers about 20 minutes ago, but the main page claimed it only had one answer (even after refreshing); It had only 1 *upvoted* answer at the time. Now it has 5 answers still, 3 upvoted, and the main page now shows 5 answers. Is this a result of caching, or some function that I am unable to infer?

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131373/clicking-on-an-old-answer-in-your-profile-answers-tab-then-hitting-back-in-th), the problem being that it was caching the older versions of the page. If you're behind a proxy, the proxy can also serve up *stale* versions of the page.