# Moderator message asking about a blocked account

Tags: support, moderators

I received a message from a moderator, asking me if my account is related to another closed account. I saw the message, but I was not available to answer because some changes at worked were being made.

Then when I logged in today, I saw another message that said I should be in chat. But I don't know how to answer him. The inbox said there were no messages. What do I have to do? Is there any way to contact the moderator? My friend's account was blocked last week and I don't want mine to be blocked.

Note: Please understand that I'm new to this site.

Comment: There should have been links in those emails - did you click them? Did you reply to the original email?

Comment: No, now there is not link. It said that the page does not exist.

Comment: @Ligth: Were you logged in at the time?

Comment: @Manishearth Yes, why?

Comment: @Ligth: Well, certain links (like links to mod messages) show a 404 unless you're logged in.

Comment: Did you receive this as an email or a notification in your inbox on Stack Overflow?

Comment: As a notification

Comment: This sounds like it might be the same situation as here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163716/suddenly-logged-in-as-another-user and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86033/hijacked-session-signed-in-as-someone-else

Answer (score 12):

That was me. I sent you a chat ping to a private room to ask a question, but accidentally deleted the room for some reason. Just wanted a clarification on something not worthy of a mod message.

I'll double check what I was doing and see if I need to contact you again. Sorry for the confusion!