# Other user profile when I access the site

Tags: bug

So it's the second time happening today. I enter the site and on the up-right other user's picture rep and badges appear. I clicked on it and it took me to his profile page, when on his page the up-right part with picture rep and badges turned to normal. It happened now and about 2 hours ago, and there were 2 different profiles. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you on a school or office network that includes a transparent caching proxy?

Comment: I'm at the office but I don't know about the proxy. It's not the first time I access the site from work.

Comment: The other user may well be *in your office too*; if there is a transparent proxy that caches too much, you'll see pages cached that the other user visited recently. Vice versa, *your* pages are also going to be cached and shown to the other user.

Comment: I'd switch to using `https://stackoverflow.com` while at the office to prevent this.

Comment: Ok, it's just strange because I accessed the site every day for the last 2 months and haven't had this problem.

Comment: Perhaps that colleague has just started using Stack Overflow from the office? It could also be that a proxy was added further upstream, by the ISP used by your office, meaning that several companies (connections) are sharing that proxy. Either way, either the proxy is new, or the fact that someone else started using Stack Overflow through that same proxy.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu is the other user from Romania as well ? Can you tell from his account ? Also, when the header loads up with his / hers profile info, are the messages in the achievements / inbox your or the other user's ? (asking cause i think they are loaded dynamically)

Comment: @MartijnPieters then wouldn't it be a problem if under the same proxy a user can see the info for other users that use that proxy as well ? 

Shouldn't some of the page be generated dynamically depending on the user logged in (and his IP + cookies ) so you only get your data and nothing else ? Regardless of what is cached in proxies or not ?

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: You can only *advice* proxies as to what to cache and what to ignore; a badly configured proxy can still ignore that information.

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: yes, the dropdowns are AJAX requests, and the contents depend on your cookies (no user id is sent along in the URL) and the caching header is set to 'private'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. But you can go around that by loading an empty 'template' page and adding data with ajax. And the ajax calls can be made to be unique so that they don't get cached.

Comment: Also, I would add that this is likely a problem at Alexandru's office and not at an ISP level, as in Romania  most companies have a dedicated IP and the ISP's don't add any proxy's.

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: I am just leaving the possibility open; it depends onthe network arrangements; say the company is a university spin-off and still uses the university network connection, for example.

Comment: Point taken. And a very good example as most of our university networks are disastrous in all regards.

Comment: @Catalin Deaconescu, I assume that the second user was also from Romania, I can't say about the first one. It didn't cross my mind to check the messages, I only saw that when I clicked up right where the profile is it took me to his profile but when I was on his profile I was viewing it as a visitor. If it happens again I will further check.

Comment: If it happens, please also send us the full URL at which it is happening - just so I can check our cache configuration on that route. Normally, we only do server-side page caching for anonymous views, for all the obvious reasons. My *guess* is that this is a misconfigured proxy, but we can at least keep options open.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Depending on how it's (mis)configured; switching to https might not stop the problem.  The Bluecoat proxy my employer runs intercepts all non-whitelisted https traffic and could in theory (I have no idea if it actually has caching capabilities) return cached copies of an https page.

Comment: @DanNeely: yeah, a proxy that forces a man-in-the-middle re-wrapping of the SSL certificate with every browser in the network including the proxy certificate is such a *wonderful* idea for security. Cough, cough *hack* cough.

Comment: @MarcGravell: why is the cache-control set to public, not private, on logged-in pages? That tells shared caches to cache such responses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if I was in a position to do so, I'd be making the same argument to higher authorities.  General stupidity not withstanding I don't do anything I'm not comfortable with coworkers/management/hr being aware of on my work computer; and wouldn't even if I had no reason to suspect my https traffic wasn't secure.

Comment: @Martijn I'm not near a PC to check: but - example page?

Comment: @MarcGravell: This very page has `Cache-Control: public, max-age=60` set on the response. Yet the response body includes my username, userid, score, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see answer added; thanks

Comment: I'm moving this to meta.SE, as it is network wide, not SO-specific

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible explanation, as noted by Martijn Pieters in the comments, is a badly posed `Cache-Control` header, which seems to be a side effect of using `[OutputCache]`, *even when we take pains to ensure that it doesn't cache for logged in users*. I've had another stab at hacking our already hacked implementation, with the result that it should now continue to behave as normal for anonymous users, but logged in users will receive `Cache-Control: private` for these pages.

I cannot say for sure whether this was the actual cause, but it is consistent with what we would expect if an intermediate proxy decided to cache.

As side notes, note that the `public` header included `no-cache="Set-Cookie"`, so this wouldn't have led to any cookie hijacking - and only applies to `GET` requests.

If you inspect this page *now* you should see this in action. I will deploy to the other sites after a brief stability check.

Comment: Confirmed that your cache control header now looks sane!

Comment: As a historical note this used to (generally) be fine before because `Vary` was set to `*`, but now that it's just `Accept-Encoding` intermediate proxies were able to more liberally cache the response (though they [sometimes incorrectly did with `Vary: *`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63845/account-mixup-on-stack-overflow) too)

Comment: @TimStone that's a red herring; that is *because of* the changes I made here; fixing that

Comment: Ah, so the response was being incorrectly cached in this case too. Hopefully they follow `Cache-Control: private` better than they followed the `Vary: *` exception.

Comment: @TimStone the "Vary" thing looks like a bug in IIS; we're wrestling with it